# can an EXTERNAL iframe be included into google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I refer to this article:

http://julip.co/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-3-loading-any-web-page-in-a-popup/

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {width:200; height:300;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://m.bing.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Source code of this extension is: http://mfi.re/?imwxngtdkhg

Howver it does not dispaly ANYTHING.

**My question is: can an EXTERNAL iframe be included into google chrome extension ?**

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can display an `iframe` inside a popup**. It's a bit heavy and I don't recommend doing it, but you can.

The problem with the extension you linked is that the `manifest.json` file is malformed:

- The `"manifest_version"` parameter is absent, and it should be set to `2`.
- The default popup of the browser action is defined using `"default_popup"`, and you are using `"popup"` instead, which is wrong.

**Here is the correct `manifest.json` file:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Mini Bing Search",
    "description": "Search Bing right from your browser without leaving your current page.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon19.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": { 
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png" 
    }
}
```

**DOWNLOAD A WORKING EXAMPLE [HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/cnozp78855hl3ik/extension-26423899.zip)**